# How can I rotate different cards using CSS?

Tags: css

What I am trying to do is have a lot of cards displayed on the screen. When you click them, they should rotate and change their color.
The problem I have is that no matter which card I click, only the first one changes, instead of the one being clicked.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8zr/2/

html:

```
<body>

    <div class="pane">
    <input type="checkbox" id="button">
    <label class="card" for="button"></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="button">
    <label class="card" for="button"></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="button">
    <label class="card" for="button"></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="button">
    <label class="card" for="button"></label>
    </div>

</body>
```

css:

```
input
    {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:none
    }
.card
    {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    display:block;
    transition: background 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    }
input:checked +.card
    {
    background:blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Select the first adjacent sibling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828608/css-select-the-first-adjacent-sibling)

Comment: There is no "first sibling" selector in CSS. You need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you're using the same ID on the three inputs and labels. As per W3C spec, IDs must be unique on a page. And that's what the `for` attribute is expecting. So change your code to look like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/GZ8zr/4/

Answer (score 1):

You have the same id "button" three times. Therefore - at least on my browser and presumably yours too - each label is `for` the first checkbox. AFAIK this behavior is also undefined, since the standard expects unique ids for any given page (see below).

[This fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xr8UG/1/) with the `display:none` removed for the checkboxes demonstrates that clicking on any of the labels causes the *first* checkbox to be toggled.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8zr/7/), on the other hand, demonstrates your code working properly when the ids are unique.

---

Also note that [the HTML standard specifies that ids must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2):

> id = name [CS]
>   :   This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your inputs and labels are all targeting just the first input tag - which is incorrect. Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GZ8zr/6/

If your input has id "button", then no other inputs can have that id. Even if you do that, the first input checkbox will be checked - html itself enforcing that there is just one unique ID every html page.

HTML:

```
<div class="pane">
<input type="checkbox" id="button1">
<label class="card" for="button1"></label>

<input type="checkbox" id="button2">
<label class="card" for="button2"></label>

<input type="checkbox" id="button3">
<label class="card" for="button3"></label>

<input type="checkbox" id="button4">
<label class="card" for="button4"></label>
</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: You need to change the ID on your first checkbox to `button1`

Comment: thanks for the tip..must have missed that. quickly changed. thnx again!

Answer (score -2):

All cards must have a unique identifier. You are clicking on a card and CSS is running on the first thing that the class is applied to (in this case the first card). I would use jquery to select the specific card you want the class applied to -> $(this). Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, I wouldn't recommend adding JavaScript or jQuery to a project that doesn't absolutely need it.